# Search for a substring in a stream of characters

Tags: grep

How do I search for a sequence of bytes (FEEDFEED00000002) in hex code and display 1000 bytes after this sequence?

It's the beginning of a lost file I am looking for on a Linux partition. This command outputs harddrive contents in hex code:

```
sudo cat /dev/sda1 | hexdump -v -e '"" 1/1 "%02X" ""'
# output is FF45D5003E... etc
```

I need to search for FEEDFEED00000002 in the output.

Answer (score 2):

grep can search for binary patterns, it may be more efficient than examining the output of hexdump, which will be roughly 3 times larger:

```
grep -b `echo -e "\xFE\xED\xFE\xED.."` /dev/sda1 | cut -d: -f1 >offsets
```

Will give you the byte offsets; then you could extract 1k blocks with

```
for o in `cat offsets`
do
    dd if=/dev/sda1 of=block.{$o} bs=1 count=1000 skip=$o
done
```

Which will create one file per matching offset. You can always run `hexdump` on these afterwards.